# Dropbox API uploading mp3 file

Tags: python, file-upload, upload, mp3, dropbox-api

I am making a Python script to upload mp3 files in my Music folder to Dropbox, but I cannot figure out how to do so. I am using Dropbox API and here's my code

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('*******')
dbx.users_get_current_account()

f = open('Channa Mereya.mp3', 'rb')
dbx.files_upload(bytes(f.read()), 'Channa Mereya.mp3')
```

but I get the error

```
dropbox.stone_validators.ValidationError: 'Channa Mereya.mp3' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*)|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

I don't know much about regex patterns.
Also while reading API documentation, `files_upload` takes first argument as bytes, I don't why it takes bytes.

I also tried to just pass the path of mp3 file instead of opening and passing the file like

```
dbx.files_upload("/home/username/python projects/Channa Mereya.mp3", 'Channa Mereya.mp3')
```

Here `Channa Mereya.mp3` is a mp3 file stored in the same directory as the 
script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying a file path to upload to in Dropbox API v2, the path should have a leading `"/"` to identify root. So, the second parameter to `files_upload` should look like `'/Channa Mereya.mp3'`.

The error is indicating that your path value `'Channa Mereya.mp3'` doesn't match the allowed pattern, i.e., it doesn't have that leading slash.